# Change text size to not exceed width of form input

Tags: javascript, css, font-size

I have a form `<input>` that spans the width of the page, and with a font size of `2em` (let's call that the base font size).

I don't want the inputed text to get cut off/overflow if it should exceed the width of the field, so my question is: **how do I detect when the field text is overflowing the field and lower the font-size so it all stays within view?** Conversely, how do I detect when the user starts deleting characters and in turn increase the font-size, but not higher than the base font size?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a fixed-width font?

Comment: Perhaps you could predetermine the number of characters it takes to fill the width, then if character count reaches maximum, change the font size. This could work if the input field width is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dMXhu/)

```
<input type="text" name="younameit" id="demo">
$('#demo').inputfit();
```

And, These css attributes will help to retain size of input while the font size changes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dMXhu/1/)

```
min-height: 30px;
min-width: 500px;
line-height: 30px;
```

https://github.com/vxsx/jquery.inputfit.js

Comment: What that plugin does is maybe the only possible solution: clone the field's contents into a div, and compare to the field's width, trying to account for margins/paddings/borders. (I'm adding this note because this is a jQuery answer to a non-jQuery question, so the ones who don't want jQuery can have an idea about what should be done).